# F# compile on mac os x

Tags: macos, f#, mono

I'm trying to compile F# on Mac OS X Yosemite following the instructions at http://fsharp.org/use/mac/

When I make fsharp I get the following error:

```
/mono64/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : PCL Reference Assemblies not installed.
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I thought (but I may be wrong) that you need to have an existing installation of Mono (from package) to build the latest version (from source). I'm not sure if this is required - but it certainly worked for me recently...

Comment: Thanks Tomas - I'll give that a whirl. In which case perhaps the fsharp.org directions need to be updated?

Comment: I was given the answer to this by Robin Neatherway on the fsharp-opensource group. PKG_CONFIG_PATH needs to be set to reference the source build of mono. In my case that meant setting it as follows ```export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mono64/lib/pkgconfig/``` prior to running autogen. I can now build.